# Align two responsive divs, side by side

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment

I'm trying to code a simple comparison table, but I can't get what I want to.

An image is worth a thousand words, so I sketched what I would like to get:

[image]

Currently, the website page is a single column of divs (represented above by the "other content" area). The grey area underneath the two divs is just to represent the div I'm using to contain them, but I don't need it.

So, basically, I just want to add another div containing two divs that look like in the image, but every suggestion is welcome : )

Also, the divs must be responsive, of course ; )

EDIT 1

As suggested, here's the code that worked so far: I tried many things, anyway once I add some space around the divs, they start to get messed up. Most of it the code is unnecessary, I know : (

```css
* {
color: #fff;
font-family: "Avenir", sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;

border 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
display: flex;
align-content: center;

margin-bottom: 20px;
width: 100%;

background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.content {
width: 100%;
}

.container {
background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 95%);

margin: auto;
padding: 0%;
}

.comparecontainer {
margin: 0%;
float: left;

height: auto;
width: 50%;
}

.compare {
padding: 5%;

height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.lite {
background-color: hsl(40, 100%, 50%);
}

.full {
background-color: hsl(150, 80%, 50%);
}



.button {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
color: #fff;
font-family: ;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 200%;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
padding: 1% 3%;
border: 2px solid #fff;
border-radius: 0;
outline: none;
}

.button:hover,
.button:active {
background-color: #fff;
}

.button:hover .lite {
color: hsl(40, 100%, 50%);
}

.button .full:hover {
color: hsl(150, 80%, 50%);
}



h2 {
font-size: 36px;
margin: auto;
}

h3 {
font-size: 21px;
margin: 2.5% 0;
}

h4 {
font-size: 21px;
margin: 10% 0;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 5% 0;
}

li {
margin: 2.5% 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
<div class="content">

    <div class="comparecontainer">
    <div class="compare lite">
<h2>First DIV</h2>
<h3>Subtitle</h3>

    <ul>
<li><b>item</b> one</li>
<li><b>item</b> two</li>
<li><b>item</b> three</li>
<li><b>item</b> four</li>
<li>-</li>
<li>-</li>
<li>-</li>
<li>feature</li>
    </ul>

<h4>text</h4>

<a href="#" class="button lite">button</a>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="comparecontainer">
    <div class="compare full">
<h2>Second DIV</h2>
<h3>Subtitle</h3>

    <ul>
<li><b>item</b> one</li>
<li><b>item</b> two</li>
<li><b>item</b> three</li>
<li><b>item</b> four</li>
<li><b>item</b> five</li>
<li><b>item</b> six</li>
<li><b>item</b> seven</li>
<li><b>feature</b></li>
    </ul>

<h4>text</h4>

<a href="#" class="button full">button</a>

    </div>
    </div>

</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code what you have tried?

Comment: You should post some code to show what you've tried so far. Do the columns need to be the same height?

Comment: @SanjeevK sure : )

Comment: @MyiEye done : ) Yes, they need to be identical, even if the content is different. Ideally, they should fit in the lite grey div underneath, but adapt to the content in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `calc` css feature like so:

```
width: calc(50% - 32px);
```

It helps laying out percentage based layouts!

Edit: I just realised you wanted to have content with unknown height inside the boxes. So I added a `flex` display as well.

[CODEPEN DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/YZNjJb)

```
div {
  display:block; 
  width: 100%; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.wrapper {
    margin-top: 12px;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 32px 16px;
}

.wrapper > div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(50% - 32px);
    float: left;
    margin: 0 16px;
}

body {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work pretty well! I'm now trying to make it as responsive as possible, because you used px in here.
Ironically, removing the calc function seems to achieve what I was looking for: probably, it was just a matter of bad html syntax, so to speak!

Comment: Cool, glad you found it useful. Help me know how I can help you further. If you are happy with my answer please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Yep, it's been of help, at least for clearing the HTML ; )
I'll probably answer the thread myself once I merge everything, but for now yours it's the closest answer : )

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
body
{
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
#other
{

  max-width: 540px;

  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;

  vertical-align: top;


}
.container
{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;  
}
.left-div
{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.right-div
{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.left-text, .right-text
{
  font: 300 16px/1.6 'Helvetica Neue' sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
  .left-div, .right-div
    {
       max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/7gkjn9gd/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the two divs to be identical, regardless of the content : (